# gulp-install not install the dependencies with vinyl file

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-install

I'm a beginner of gulp plugin. I want install dependencies by merged package.json. The code as follow.

```
gulp.task('install-dependencies', function () {
    var through = require('through2');
    var npm = require('npm');
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    var file = require('gulp-file');
    var install = require('gulp-install');
    var path = require('path');
    var npmLoad = Promise.promisify(npm.load);
    var plugins = {};

    //for test
    var lastFile;

    gulp.src([`${PATH.plugin}**/package.json`])
        .pipe(through.obj(function parse_plugins(file, enc, cb) {
            if (file.isNull()) {
                cb();
                return;
            }

            if (file.isStream()) {
                this.emit('error', new gulpUtil.PluginError('package-concat', 'Streaming not supported'));
                cb();
                return;
            }
            let fileContent = {};
            try {
                fileContent = JSON.parse(file.contents.toString())
            } catch (e) {
                this.emit('error', new gulpUtil.PluginError('package-concat', `file '${file.path}' not a json file!`));
                throw e;
            }
            plugins = Object.assign({}, plugins, fileContent.dependencies)
            lastFile = file;
            cb();
        },
        function install(cb){
            let fileContent = {};
            fileContent.name = "test";
            fileContent.dependencies = plugins;
            var file = new gulpUtil.File({
                base: path.join(__dirname, './'),
                cwd: __dirname,
                path: path.join(__dirname, './package.json'),
                contents: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(fileContent))
            });
            this.push(file);
            cb();
        }
    ))
    .pipe(install());
})
```

But, The dependencies not install as expected. And the log as follow.

> [14:50:37] Starting 'install-dependencies'...
>
> [14:50:37] Finished 'install-dependencies' after 205 ms
>
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture:   fsevents@1.0.11

Answer (score 0):

What is your operating system ?

You might find something similar [here](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/1212).

Sounds like you can try to uninstall everything and start again from scratch (or just delete your node_module folder and use npm install). Not sure though, depends a lot on your operating system according to the error itself.

Comment: OS:win10, Node:v5.9.1,npm:3.8.7

Comment: Check here : https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12185
At the moment there is no answer, but there might be one as I'm typing or in few days ...
Did you try to remove the **node_module** folder and then run `npm install` ?

Comment: `npm install` just install my devDependencies and core dependencies. others dependencies will  be install by gulp task when part of package.json has been collected and merged.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but this worked for some people according to github.com/npm/npm/issues . Anyway, I'm using gulp too with no error, I'll try to reproduce your error and then I'll let you know.

Comment: I debugged this, I found `gulp-install` just exec `npm install` in vinyl file path directory, But there are not found `package.json` file in disk. Maybe it generate this.